# database connection closing in doctrine 2 and symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I was wondering whether the database connection gets closed after the request is completed in symfony 2 application. Does symfony 2 handles the closing of database connection by calling close function of doctrine or symfony does not deal with the closing at all. I have walked over many tutorials of symfony 2 but never found that they manually close the database connection. So should I have to manually close the database connection after the request is completed ? I also found out that doctrine uses persistent connection. Does that mean i dont have to worry about closing database connection. How does doctrine 2 handle the closing operation ? If I have large number of requests, I will be left with many open connections.Could somebody explain to me for the case when there could be many concurrent users logging into my site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will take care of closing your connections after each request.  No need to worry about it.  And Doctrine 2 does not use persistent connections.